# how to pass one variable from one controller to other controller in alloy

Tags: javascript, arrays, titanium-alloy

My code is below. i want to pass the value of 'get item' from the controller named as 'project' to other controller named as 'project list'. can anyone one help me please

```
      function callPopup(e)
       {
         var itemselect =e.itemIndex;
           if(itemselect==1)
           {
            getitem=items[3].image1;
           }
         return getitem;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments as below :

```
Alloy.createController('other_controller',{getitem:getitem}).getView();
```

And in the other_controller you can simply retrieve it as

```
args.getitem;
```